# Configure Camel routes from outside JAR in Camel-Spring-Boot setup

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, config

My goal is to have a simple way of running Camel with a few routes in a dynamic fashion. Ideally, I'd like to run something like this

`java -jar camel.jar routes.xml`

which allows adjusting the routes in `routes.xml` without changing the Jar. But if the `routes.xml` file is read from a relative filesystem location, that would work too.

I've generated an application using `camel-archetype-spring-boot` using `mvn archetype:generate`. I put this line in `resources/application.properties`:

`camel.springboot.xmlRoutes = classpath:routes.xml`

which loads the routes defined in `resources/routes.xml`. So I can configure the routes but must rebuild the Jar everytime I want to adjust something. Now how can I load `routes.xml` from outside the Jar?

Maybe the path I've chosen is not ideal to get a Camel instance I can quickly reconfigure. If there is a better way, I'd like to hear that. I'm a bit lost with all the options.

I found [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config) in the Spring manual, but that only explains how to change properties. I also found a question that talks about how to [exclude the configuration XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46121704/excluding-xml-and-properties-from-standalone-jar-with-spring-boot-maven-plugin). Unfortunately it doesn't say how the external XML is loaded instead.

Comment: You can try with `file:xxx` to load the files outside the JAR

Comment: Thanks @claus-ibsen! That works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ClausIbsen: The file is read from outside the Jar with:

```
camel.springboot.xmlRoutes = file:routes.xml
```

Simple, once you know :-)

Comment: See the documentation (that property above is documented with file: or classpath: as prefix) - https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/spring-boot.html

Comment: Yep it's all there. I must have overlooked that.